# Does split method in python returned something containing \u for some characters and how to get rid of it?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I have a unicode string:

```
s = "ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ ᠲᠠᠯ᠎ᠠ ᠶᠢᠨ ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ"
```

the split method it returns is somewhat changed, with a `\u180e` in the second word.

```
>>> print(s.split())
['ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ', 'ᠲᠠᠯ\u180eᠠ', 'ᠶᠢᠨ', 'ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ', 'ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ']
```

What I want to get is:

```
['ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ', 'ᠲᠠᠯ᠎ᠠ ᠶᠢᠨ', 'ᠶᠢᠨ', 'ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ', 'ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ']
```

What is the reason causing this, and how to solve it?

Comment: I copied the text in your question and pasted into my editor & there was a unicode character in there. It's not being rendered here i think but it's there.

Comment: According to Google, `\u180e` is the Mongolian Vowel Separator. It may have slipped into `s` and could not be converted.

Comment: The true trouble may be caused by the character `'\u202f'`, a _narrow no-break space_. You cannot see it in `s` (because it is _narrow_?), but it exists.

Comment: Sorry, I don't much understand your comments. But \u202f and \u180e characters are really annoying. Why list can't handle them well?

Comment: The characters are handled completely fine. This is all about display only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the split function, but with the list itself.

```
>>> s = ["ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ ᠲᠠᠯ᠎ᠠ ᠶᠢᠨ ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ"]
>>> print(s)
['ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ ᠲᠠᠯ\u180eᠠ ᠶᠢᠨ ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ']
```

You should still be able to use the list normally, because it corrects itself when the element is used.

```
>>> s = "ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ ᠲᠠᠯ᠎ᠠ ᠶᠢᠨ ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ"
>>> s = s.split()
>>> [print(e) for e in s]
ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ
ᠲᠠᠯ᠎ᠠ
ᠶᠢᠨ
ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ
ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ
```

Comment: Yes, it is about the list but not about split. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for the difference between the two is the `print(s)` displays the_ representation_ of each element in the list, whereas the list comprehension displays each element as a string.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode

U+180E is a space character until Uncode 6.3.0 so if python implements a earlier Unicode spec than i guess split() would break on all space characters. You could work arround this by giving split an argument if you want to only split on certain characters (`s.split(" ")`) that would give you:

```
>>> s.split(" ")
['ᠤᠷᠢᠳᠤ', 'ᠲᠠᠯ\u180eᠠ\u202fᠶᠢᠨ', 'ᠬᠠᠪᠲᠠᠭᠠᠢ', 'ᠬᠡᠪᠲᠡᠭᠡ']
```

Comment: Interestingly, `str.isspace("\u180e")` is `False`.